# Multivariate Statistics: Show that SST = SSTR + SSE (More detailed question below)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Show that

$$\sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} (y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{..})(y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{..})^T = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} (y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{. j})(y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{. j})^T + \sum_{j=1}^J n_{j}  (\bar{y}_{. j} - \bar{y}_{..})(\bar{y}_{. j} - \bar{y}_{..})^T $$

---

So far I've tried to use the following property for SSTR:

$$SSTR = \sum_{j=1}^J n_{j} \bar{y}_{. j} \bar{y}_{. j}^T - n \bar{y}_{..} \bar{y}_{..}^T$$

$$SST = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} {y}_{ij} {y}_{ij}^T - n \bar{y}_{..} \bar{y}_{..}^T$$

Within the equality SST = SSTR + SSE I can see that I can cancel $n \bar{y}_{..} \bar{y}_{..}^T$ but now I'm unsure of how to implement SSE. I tried expanding within the double summation in SSE but wasn't sure how to proceed from there.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
y_{11} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n_1 1} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ y_{1J} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n_J J} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot}
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} y_{11} - \overline y_{\cdot1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n_1 1} - \overline y_{\cdot 1} \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ y_{1J} - \overline y_{\cdot J} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n_J J} - \overline y_{\cdot J} \end{array} \right] + \left[ \begin{array}{c} \overline y_{\cdot1} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ \overline y_{\cdot 1} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ \overline y_{\cdot J} - \overline y _{\cdot\cdot} \\ \vdots \\ \overline y _{\cdot J} - \overline y_{\cdot\cdot} \end{array} \right] 
$$
Show that the dot-product of the two vectors on the right is $0.$ That can be done by showing that the sum of the first $n_1$ products is $0,$ then that the sum of the next $n_2$ products is $0,$ and so on.

For two vectors $a,b,$ you have
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2 & = (a+b)\cdot(a+b) = a\cdot a+a\cdot b+b\cdot a + b\cdot b \\[10pt]
& = \|a\|^2 + 0 + 0 + \|b\|^2 \text{ if } a\cdot b=0.
\end{align}
Apply that to the two vectors on the right side above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may be rusty on my Linear Algebra but why do we want to show that the dot product is 0?

Also, can we not just add the vectors as you have them presented?

Comment: Correction: I see why we can't just add them as is (sorry. Just had work all day and am a little brain-dead). I'll give this a shot. Thank you!

Comment: @Nicklovn : I'm not sure I understand your comment. The two vectors displayed on the right side at the top of my answer can be added and you get some trivial cancelations and then the vector on the left side remains. But the question is what happens when you square all the entries.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I thought you meant the dot product of SSRT and SSE. I understand now. Thank you for your help!